# How to get Employee List when selecting department?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

i have a many2many field called department_ids and one more many2many field called employee_ids.I need to generate the employees lists of  that departments which i selected in department_ids field.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use same **relation table** for both many2many fields. If you use same **relation table** for both fields any change in either field will reflect in both.

The syntax for Many2Many fields is :-

```
    fields.Many2many(comodel_name=None, relation=None, column1=None, column2=None, string=None)
```

Here comodel_name is the name of target model,
and relation is name of table that store relation in database. ie it will create a table in database with the given name, which store the relation,
column1 and column2  are the name of columns of relation-table in database.

Talking about to and fro relation between two objects(tables). Lets assume that our objects are teachers and subjects, and we want a to and fro relation, i.e.  we can add teachers to subject from subject-form-view and we can also add subjects to teacher from teacher-form-view, either way it have to reflect in both sides. This we can achieve using same relation-table for both Many2many fields. For more understanding, refer code

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    _name = "teacher.teacher"

    name = fields.Char(string='Teacher Name')
    subject_ids = fields.Many2many('subject.subject', 'teacher_sub_rel', 'subject_id', 'teacher_id', string='Teachers')

class Subject(models.Model):
    _name = "subject.subject"

    name = fields.Char(string='Subject Name')
    teacher_ids = fields.Many2many('teacher.teacher', 'teacher_sub_rel', 'teacher_id', 'subject_id', string='Subject')
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you department model has a one2many to employees `employee_ids`, try this:

```py
@api.onchage('department_ids')
def onchage_department(self):
        """
            new api support this now
        """
        if self.department_ids:                        # this is o2m of departement
            self.employee_ids = self.department_ids.mapped('employee_ids') 
        else:
            self.employee_ids = False
```